# How can I test the convergence of series $ \int_{0}^{1} \frac{\ln (x)}{(1-x^6)(\arccos x)}\,dx $

Tags: calculus, improper-integrals

I have found that this function is continuous from $(0,1)$, and the problematic points are $0$ and $1$.

For point $0$, I tried to compare it with $\log(x)$ and found that it converges.
For point $1$, I found the limit of $\cfrac {f(x)}{g(x)}$, whereas $f(x)$ is the integrand and $g(x) = \cfrac{(x-1)}{(1-x)(1-x)^{1/2}}$ as $x \to 1$ and also found that it converges.
So to conclude this integrand converges absolutely.

However, I still feel like it still needs improvement. I would appreciate any comment that contributes to the answer to this problem. Thank you

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Comment: Thank you so much for your comment. I will try to rewrite it again

Comment: I think you may be confused on the definition of *absolute convergence.* This has to do with $\int_a ^b |f(x)|\text{d}x$ vs $\int_a ^b f(x)\text{d}x$. Notice on the interval $[0,1]$, your function is always negative. So, the integral of the absolute value will just be of opposite sign as the original. In other words, absolute convergence is not something you should be concerned about.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a careful treatment of this problem. Since $y=1-x^6$ and $y=\arccos(x)$ are both positive and decreasing functions on the domain $(0,0.5)$ we can say for any $0<x<0.5$ that $$0<\frac{1}{(1-x^6)\arccos(x)}<\frac{1}{(1-(0.5)^6)\arccos(.5)}=\frac{64}{21 \pi}$$ Since $y= -\ln(x)$ is positive on $(0,0.5)$ we get $0<-\frac{\ln(x)}{(1-x^6)\arccos(x)}<-\frac{64\ln(x)}{21\pi}$ for any $0<x<0.5$. Because $\int_0^{0.5}-\frac{64\ln(x)\mathrm{d}x}{21\pi}$ converges to $\frac{32(\ln(2)+1)}{21\pi}$ we know by direct comparison that $\int_0^{0.5}\frac{-\ln(x)\mathrm{d}x}{(1-x^6)\arccos(x)}$ is necessarily convergent. On the other hand, because $-\frac{\ln(x)}{1-x^6}\rightarrow \frac{1}{6}$ as $x\rightarrow 1^{-}$ we can find $\delta_0>0$ such that $\Big|-\frac{\ln(x)}{1-x^6}-\frac{1}{6}\Big|<\frac{1}{10}$ for any $x\in (1-\delta_0,1)$ This implies $0<-\frac{\ln(x)}{1-x^6}<\frac{4}{15}$ for any $x$ belonging to the interval $(1-\delta,1)$ where $\delta=\min\{0.5,\delta_0\}$. Using the fact that $y=\arccos(x)$ is positive on $(1-\delta,1)$ we get $0<-\frac{\ln(x)}{(1-x^6)\arccos(x)}<\frac{4}{15\arccos(x)}$ on $(1-\delta,1).$  The improper integral $\int_{1-\delta}^1\frac{4\mathrm{d}x}{14\arccos(x)}$ converges by limit comparison test to $\int_{1-\delta}^{1}\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{\sqrt{1-x}}$ hence so must $\int_{1-\delta}^1-\frac{\ln(x)\mathrm{d}x}{(1-x^6)\arccos(x)}$ Since $\int_{0.5}^{1-\delta}-\frac{\ln(x)\mathrm{d}x}{(1-x^6)\arccos(x)}$ isn't event improper, we see that $\int_0^1-\frac{\ln(x)\mathrm{d}x}{(1-x^6)\arccos(x)}$ is convergent and so must be your integral.